# Delete array item based on dictionary value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to write a orientation routine for a 3-axis accelerometer.  The part I am getting stuck on is, I have one dict with all my axis' listed, after taking the 'z-axis' reading, I want to remove that axis from the Availiable_axis list.  Here is a portion of my code that demonstrates what I am trying to do.

```
import operator

Readings1 = { 0:{'x':0.1, 'y':-1, 'z':-0.1}, 1:{'x':.4, 'y':-.1, 'z':-0.1}, 
        2:{'x':-0.4, 'y':-.8, 'z':-0.1}, 3:{'x':0.1, 'y':-.1, 'z':-0.6}, 
        4:{'x':0.1, 'y':-.2, 'z':0.4}}

SetupValue = {'Axis':{'x-axis':'x','y-axis':'y','z-axis':'z'}}

Available_axis = [SetupValue['Axis']['x-axis'], SetupValue['Axis']['y-axis'], SetupValue['Axis']['z-axis']]
axes = Readings1[0]

print axes

for key in axes:
    axes[key] = abs(axes[key])

print axes


print (max(axes.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))[0])
Available_axis.pop(max(axes.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))[0],0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And why/how isn't the code working?

Comment: `Available_axis.pop()
print Available_axis`  -->` (x,y) `  ...   or do you also want to remove the z-axis from your readings? By the way, I don't think a dictionary is a good store for these kind of data. Dictionaries (Hashtables) are good for fast lookup of nonsequential keys, but you have sequential data. A list or numpy array would be good enough. If you want column names, look at pandas.

Comment: `Available_axis` is a list, not a dict. pop() for list only takes one optional argument, an index value.

Comment: @StaticVoid. `pop` when used on a list removes the last value, which in his case is `z`.

Comment: @roadrunner66 two arguments are passed to pop - max(...)[0] and 0.

Comment: @roadrunner66: The final program doesn't use a dictionary for that.  That was a placeholder for my simulation program to imitate the readings from the accelerometer as I go through my calibration routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available_axis is a list.  When popping from a list, you must specify the *integer* location.

You can also have a short list comprehension that removes the target variable.

```
Available_axis = [x for x in Available_axis 
                  if x != max(axes.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))[0]]
```